# Hello World AngularJS directive broken

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

This code is just supposed to print "Hello world" using an AngularJS directive, but instead of that, the page is blank when I load it in my browser.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ngClassifieds</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="ngClassifieds" ng-controller="classifiedsCtrl">

        <hello-world></hello-world>

        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="components/classifieds.ctr.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the app.js:

```
angular
.module("ngClassifieds", ["ngMaterial"])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('teal')
    .accentPalette('orange');
})
.directive("helloWorld", function() {
    return {
        template : "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    }
});
```

The paths in the script elements are correct, there are no typos as far as I'm concerned, and I'm pretty sure nothing is wrong with my port. I'd appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, it's all normal.

Comment: what versions are you using of all these scripts?  there isn't anything that stands out here, but it's hard to reproduce a working example when the code in the question refers to `node_modules` without any versioning information...

Comment: I can't reproduce your "blank page", this code seems to work without problem:  http://plnkr.co/edit/jgZ1CyzOZ6Y9wJvJ3A3F?p=preview  This is assuming, of course, I have all the versions of the files the same as what you are using...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the references for the angular-material, because its a dependency,

**DEMO**

```js
angular
.module("ngClassifieds", ["ngMaterial"])
.directive("helloWorld", function() {
    return {
        template : "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ngClassifieds</title>
       <link data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="ngClassifieds">
        <hello-world></hello-world>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading **Angular-material.js** file

```
.module("ngClassifieds", ["ngMaterial"])
```

-------------------------------------^

```
<!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>


<!-- Angular Material Javascript now available via Google CDN; version 1.0.7 used here -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.7/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Refere [Angular-Material Git-Hub page](https://github.com/angular/material) for more info